# How to run new relic in Java Spring boot jpa application

Tags: java, spring-boot, newrelic

I am trying to implement newrelic in my spring boot JPA project.

I am using this link to implement this. [new relic guid for spring boot](https://docs.newrelic.com/install/java/?deployment=maven&framework=springboot)

Now I have installed newrelic-java-7.9.0.zip ([new relic zip](https://download.newrelic.com/newrelic/java-agent/newrelic-agent/7.9.0/))from this link and changed the yml as per my requirment.

I am not able to understand what to do next as per the link. also how can run this in production environment.

AFter researching on internet I got this command to execute :

```
java -javagent:<path to your new relic jar>\newrelic.jar -jar <path to your application jar>\<you rapplication jar name>.jar
```

Now I have new relic jar but i don't have jar of my application in target folder. i am ruuning an application by clicking on play window. (Can not see any jar though target folder is getting created.)

1. How to run this in local
2. How to run this in production (How to make this command production ready)

Comment: To get the jar in the target folder you need to build it. Using maven do `mvn package`.

Comment: @DhavalGajjar I am building the project but getting only .class file, and  how can i do in production build.

Comment: As per the link you have shared you using maven/spring boot. So you need to do `mvn package` on the console. Which will generate a jar file and then you can run the command.